# Android keyboard open or closed listener event not work

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to do some operation on keyboard close on Android. For this, I have tried as below

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but this `configurationNotChanged` is not triggered on my activity. What's wrong with it?

#### Do we have any other way to handling the keyboard open/close ?

Comment: There is no direct callback for keyboard show/hide. And `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called because showing a keyboard doesn't change the configuration. Check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/1889768) for details.

Comment: @Abbas I have try that method too but not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Finally I overcome my issue based on the following code

```
RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
                    contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {

                            Rect r = new Rect();
                            RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
                            contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                            int screenHeight = contentView.getRootView().getHeight();

                            // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
                            // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
                            int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

                            Log.d("Nifras", "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

                            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
                                lytMaster.setTop(0);

                            }
                            else {
                                lytMaster.setBaselineAligned(true);
                                // keyboard is closed
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution: you can find keypad is open/close
if you set your windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize. If you set it to adjustPan, it's still not possible to detect whether or not the keyboard is visible using his code snippet. To work around this, I made this tiny modification to the code above.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        ... do something here
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: How do we trigger, Key board is closed using this method

Comment: I try with adding the else part but it triggered always the keyboard is closed. my need is keyboard closed is triggered only after open is triggered

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?rq=1